# Monotonicity of measure integrals

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I know that it is true that $f$, $g$ are measurable and positive and $f\leq g$, then $\int f d\mu\leq \int g d\mu$. Is it true if $f$ and $g$ are not positive? Can I have a hint on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you don't assume that $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative $\mu$-a.e. you have to be careful about the integrals $\int f\:d\mu$ and $\int g\:d\mu$ being well defined; not necessarily finite, but you could wind up with a $\infty-\infty$ situation and that's definitely an issue.

A hint I would give you is to write $$f=f^+-f^-\quad g=g^+-g^-$$ 
and see what are the possibilities from there.

Hope it's helpful.